# Scala equivalent for Java stream findFirst, filter, map

Tags: scala

I have java code shown below, how to convert it to scala?

```
feature.getFeatures()
            .stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getFeatureName().equals(feature))
            .findFirst()
            .map(f -> f.Accounts().contains(accountId))
            .orElse(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see `filter` or `find` chained with `map`, think `collect` or `collectFirst`

So something like this should work:

```
feature.getFeatures()
  .collectFirst {
    case f if f.getFeatureName().equals(feature) =>
      f.Accounts().contains(accountId)
  }.getOrElse(true)
```